# Images in documentation Xcode not working

Tags: ios, xcode, documentation

I'm trying to show an image in the documentation in Xcode.

Like this:

```
/**
 An example of using *images* to display a web image

 ![Xcode icon](http://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/assets/elements/icons/128x128/xcode.png "Some hover text")

 */
func enableClear() {
    self.cancelIconView.isEnabled = true
}
```

However, it simply ends up like:

[image]

I'm using the exact same example as in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/Images.html